# Using ^ with a variable

Tags: r

I know that using `grep` in R, if you want to find a certain string at the beginning, you use `^`, but how do I use it with a variable?

```
txt <- c("the cat ate the bill", "bill was late")
```

then

```
grep("^bill", txt)
```

returns `2`.

I want to write a function that takes a variable word `x` as input and finds if a line in `txt` begins with that word.
My first attempt is:

```
extract_word<-function(x){
                    grep(^x, txt)
                    }
```

but I get an error:

> error unexpected ^ in:
>   "extract_word<-function(x, txt){
>       grep(^

Comment: Unless you're using regular expressions, this functionality is provided by `?startsWith` -- `startsWith(txt, x)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `pattern` argument to `grep` is just a string. If you want your pattern string to be the value of `x` with a `^` in front of it, then just create that string. `paste0` is handy for sticking strings together with no spaces:

```
grep(paste0("^", x), txt)
```

Using your example:

```
txt <- c("the cat ate the bill", "bill was late")

x = 'bill'
grep(paste0("^", x), txt)
# [1] 2
```